# Типизация языка С++

Tags: c++, типизация

С++ — это статически типизированный язык. Я не могу понять, почему так, если, например, понижающее приведение типов (dynamic cast, разумеется) в ветке наследования с полиморфным родителем является проверкой типов *во время выполнения* программы.

То есть если вкратце, то меня смущает то, что все называют этот ЯП статически типизированным, в то время, когда тут есть элементы динамической типизации.

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я понимаю, в языках с динамической типизацией (например, Python, JavaScript, Lisp  ..., не говоря уж о разных Shell-ах) один и тот же **идентификатор** (переменная) может иметь значения **разных типов** во время выполнения программы.

В C++ же, тип данных, значения которого может принимать переменная, определяется статически (во время написания программы).

Поэтому наличие механизма [RTTI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) (в частности `dynamic cast`), проводящего некоторые проверки типов во время выполнения, не делает C++ языком с динамической типизацией.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, потому что тип наследника ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ типом родителя, так что проверка допустимости типов все-таки выполняется во время компиляции, т.е. является статической.

Comment: Such operator as dynamic_cast works in runtime!

Comment: @Semerkin Но мы точно знаем заранее, что это могут быть только наследники класса! Компилятор проверит обязательно, вызвать `dynamic_cast<int>(double)` или еще какой бред вам не дадут! Потому - статическая типизация...